# What is the slice.call() doing in get() jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to jquery and basically, I was just looking at the source of the the `get()` function in jquery and it looks something like below (Jquery 11.1.3) :

```
get: function( num ) {
    return num != null ?

        // Return just the one element from the set
        ( num < 0 ? this[ num + this.length ] : this[ num ] ) :

        // Return all the elements in a clean array
        slice.call( this );
},
```

Now I understand most part of this function, I have used my basic understanding of js to make sense of what this function is doing and heres what I think, the return statement is a ternary operator that will check if `num` is a negative or a positive number (i.e. num < 0) , and will conclude to a given condition,

If `num` is a negative number `this[ num + this.length ]` is returned and if not

```
this[ num ]
```

will be returned , ok , fair enough , now what is the part of :

```
slice.call( this );
```

doing in this function ?

I assume it is converting a object to a array incase you pass a object instead of a pure array, I made the following function to prove my point to myself :

```
function get(elem) {
  return Array.prototype.slice.call( elem );
}


obj = {
  'name' : 'putin',
  'sname' : 'valdimar'
}

var str = get(obj);

console.log(str); // returns empty array.
```

As you can see `str` is an empty array instead of being a object that is converted to a pure array. So I guess I am missing something very trivial, but can somebody now elaborate and make sense of what is `slice.call(this)` doing in the `get()` method in jquery?

Comment: Yes, it does convert the jquery collection object to an array. However, you should try your `get` method on `{0: 'putin', 1:'valdimar', length:2}`

Comment: @Bergi am i not trying my get method on `{0: 'putin', 1:'valdimar', length:2}`  , after all i am passing `obj`  inside my custom get() function .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your assessment is correct. The jQuery object is an array-like object and [`get`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) is turning the jQuery object into a true array. This is outlined in the documentation.

For `slice` to work on an object other than an array, that object must have property keys that are integers. It must also have a `length` property:

```
Array.prototype.slice.call({ 0: 'foo', 1: 'bar', length: 2 })
// yields ['foo', 'bar']
```

Or more interestingly:

```
Array.prototype.slice.call({ 45: 'foo', 47: 'bar', length: 48 })
// [undefined × 45, "foo", undefined × 1, "bar"]
```

Comment: incidentally was reading a answer of yours just today , something about `draggable` , anyways , i learnt something new , did't quite understand the `more interestingly` part , can u elaborate , i'am curious , even if its not important .

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik: Sure, that example just shows that if you specify non-consecutive integers as keys in your object, and the `length` property is large enough to accommodate them, a sparse array is created.

Answer (score 2):

`slice.call( this );` is just forcing the output to be an array, and not an Array-like object.

If you look at the entire source, `slice` is just this:

```
var slice = Array.prototype.slice;
```

If you'll recall, each jQuery object itself is an "array-like object", as well as NodeLists, etc. In `get`, they want to make sure that the output is in fact an `Array`.

If you have a NodeList, or a jQuery object, or a plain object, for example, and you do `Array.prototype.slice.call(whateverObject)`, it'll force it to become an actual `Array` object, and you will have access to the methods of `Array.prototype`, like `forEach`, etc.

Comment: thanks a ton , buddy , learnt something new !